# I want to print 'eee fff {'e':'eee','f':'fff'}',how can i get it. (it is about __setattr__)

Tags: python

the next is my code:

```
class a:
    w={}
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        self.w[name]=value
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return self.w[name]

b=a()
b.e='eee'
b['f']='fff'
print b.e,b['f'],b.w
#error
```

what is the difference between b.e and b['f'].
thanks

Comment: Also observe what happens when you have more than once instance of `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = {}

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self.w[k] = v

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.w[k]


mc = MyClass()
mc['aa'] = 12
print mc['aa']
```

setitem/getitem is for indexed access (with square brackets) like shown above. setattr/getattr is for attribute access (i.e. mc.aa)

Answer (score 1):

__ set/getitem__() are used for indexing. Define them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any method/attribute called `self.e`

If instead, you were to say `self.w[e] = 'eee'`, then you're errors should disappear.